# Fetching data from local JSON file using axios and displaying data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

This is a local JSON file I wrote.

```
{ "data":[
    {
    "photo": "https://source.unsplash.com/aZjw7xI3QAA/1144x763",
    "caption": "Viñales, Pinar del Río, Cuba",
    "subcaption": "Photo by Simon Matzinger on Unsplash",
    "thumbnail": "https://source.unsplash.com/aZjw7xI3QAA/100x67",
    }, 
    {
    "photo": "https://source.unsplash.com/c77MgFOt7e0/1144x763",
    "caption": "La Habana, Cuba",
    "subcaption": "Photo by Gerardo Sanchez on Unsplash",
    "thumbnail": "https://source.unsplash.com/c77MgFOt7e0/100x67",
    },
    {
    "photo": "https://source.unsplash.com/QdBHnkBdu4g/1144x763",
    "caption": "Woman smoking a tobacco",
    "subcaption": "Photo by Hannah Cauhepe on Unsplash",
    "thumbnail": "https://source.unsplash.com/QdBHnkBdu4g/100x67",
    }
]
}
```

and I don't understand why can't I map value after resolving. I fetched data and resolved it, and when I call console.log(response.data) I do get the JSON object, but when I want to map it, it show me an error that photos.map isn't function.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function FetchingData() {
    const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('photos.json')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            setPhotos(response.data)
        })
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
               {photos.map(photos => (<li>{photos.photo}</li>)
               )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default FetchingData
```

Comment: The first note is that your JSON is invalid, you can validate JSON online (E.g from here jsonlint.com )

Comment: Christian's answer is the one. Put simply, EVERY axios response has the payload on its `data` property. Your payload happens to also have its own `data` property too.

Comment: @Az.Youness yes it was, a comma in the end, but it wasn't the main problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are missing a `data`. The `response` from the axios call will contain the payload (your JSON file) in `data`, i.e., `response.data`. However, that is an object (which has no `map` function). I believe you are after the array in your own `data` field, so try:

```js
            setPhotos(response.data.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your json file contains a `data` field as an array, you need to call

```js
setPhotos(response.data.data);
```

Otherwise, try to use `JSON.parse()` (even if I know axios automatically parse json as object, but you never know)